# How to upload image and then perform custom google image search based on that image in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, image-uploading, google-image-search

Smart Peoples,

I have worked on performing custom google image search like entering text and it will display a list of images ,i got that file in JSON. 
I have already referred https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

NOW I want to work on uploading  image from my app and there after i want to make google image search using that uploaded file so it will display me results that would be similar images related to that uploaded image based on pixels,view,size,etc..

for example you can check out google image search and on search bar you will see a small camera at the corner side just click on it and upload an image it will display you results similar to that uploaded image .

I want to make use of the same concept in my IOS app. please help me out as early as possible  from scratch related to this  your reply would be highly appreciable  and admired ..

THANKS , in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You need a reverse image search. There are two main players in this business: [Google](http://images.google.com/) and [Tineye](http://www.tineye.com/). Tineye was pretty cool till google arrived. Now, I prefer Google. Also, Tineye search is payed.

I have an example code for Google [here](https://github.com/madhead/google-images-search). It must be not very difficult to rewrite it with Objective-C to use in iOS devices.